# Как узнать ip адрес

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Необходимо узнать IP адрес, с которого пришел запрос к моему серверу.

Comment: Мой ip 212.66.35.189

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = ip сервера при file_get_contents($url)
И тот же  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 212.66.35.189 при переходе по ссылке с любого сайта.

Оттого и возник вопрос. Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: просто для общего образования ТС:   

   var_dump($_SERVER);

ну и конечно [это][1]

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php